# Кодировка utf-8

Tags: php

Прописываю

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>
```

на что все браузеры воедино устанавливают кодировку window-1251.
А вот если я это делаю посредством php :

```
header('Content-Type:charset=utf-8')
```

так работает. В чем дело? Читал у Котерова, что нужно изменить настройки в Денвере. Так ли это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Апач отдаёт документы в определенной кодировке, её можно перенастроить, например, вписав в .htaccess строку

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Можно изменить настройки в httpd.conf написав:

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset utf-8`

Comment: .htaccess, извиняюсь за необразованность, в каком каталоге он должен находиться? mySite/www/ или mySite/ ?

Comment: в корне папки с сайтом, рядом с файлом index.php

Comment: Спасибо за советик!

Comment: не забудьте если в CSS используете ту же кодировку прописать это в заголовке. И главное в кодировка пишется utf-8 я на эти грабли наступил когда скопировал с примера заголовок для css.